# Photoshop: Optimally arranging pictures of various sizes&aspects ratios into a new rectangular canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a bunch of images (about 15 of them) of various sizes and aspect ratios, which all need to be fitted into a large new blank image, in a sort of mosaic fashion. Since the images' sizes & aspect ratios vary considerably, there is no simple way of arranging them (e.g. they can't be arranged in a grid), and to find the optimal solution manually takes a lot of time.

Is there a way in Photoshop/GIMP to have these pictures optimally resized in the new blank slate, such as to maximise the size of each individual picture but minimise the inevitable white space remaining between them?

Comment: Have you tried using Photoshop Contact Sheet: [Photoshop Help / 
Create a contact sheet CS5](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-contact-sheet-cs5.html)?

Comment: I've looked at that, but it seems to be good only for arranging pictures in a grid, whereas in my case the pictures would look more like an irregular patchwork, if the white space in between pics is going to be minimised.

Comment: I haven't heard of any automatic way of doing this. I think the easiest way is to setup guides for how wide you want your photos to be and using an action or bulk converter to give a max-width for each image. Then it is just a drag and drop game. Another alternative is to use code to align all your images. Download a masonry plugin like [http://masonry.desandro.com/](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and use your images. You can then take screen shots to use or use as a reference for where to place images.

Comment: I saw this in another thread, I have never used this but it may be worth checking out: [http://lumens.se/tychpanel/](http://lumens.se/tychpanel/)

Comment: This is essentially a treemapping problem. You want a fixed aspect ratio algorithm and you weight the importance of the images to hint for size. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Comment: Thanks  AndrewH, those software packages look interesting, I'll see if I can get them to help

Comment: Yorik - interesting, didn't know about this. Is there a software that can arrange my pics according to the treemapping algorithms?

Comment: Hey @wildetudor, I would check out the site [http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for that type of question. Make sure to be specific about your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thought of 3 different techniques that you can try.

The easiest way to get a masonry layout is by using code. I would look into using the masonry plugin by: http://masonry.desandro.com/. You can then either take screenshots for use or as a reference guide to placing images in Photoshop.

You can manually make all of the image widths in Photoshop the same with an action and drag n drop the images into the new document.

I saw this in another thread, I have never used this but it may be worth checking out: http://lumens.se/tychpanel/. This plugin for Photoshop will automate the process of aligning images next to each other.